# Modifying regex group priority

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following Regex:

`Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<g1>a?)(?<g2>a?)(?<g3>b?)(?<g4>b?)");`

and a string

```
string str = @"ab";
```

When applying this regex to the string I get

```
 g1 -> "a", g2 -> "", g3 -> "b",  g4 -> ""
```

Is it possible to modify this regex to get

```
 g1 -> "a", g2 -> "", g3 -> "",  g4 -> "b"
```

?
That is I want to have higher priority for g4 than for g3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with a "[lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)" (compared to the default "greedy") `?`. Try this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<g1>a?)(?<g2>a?)(?<g3>b??)(?<g4>b?)");
```

Comment: But there appeared another problem. If this regular expression is applied to 'aabb' I get g1 -> 'a', g2 -> 'a', g3 -> '', g4 -> 'b';
but not g1 -> 'a', g2 -> 'a', g3 -> 'b', g4 -> 'b'. I need the second variant.

Comment: @Stuff - use `^(?<g1>a?)(?<g2>a?)(?<g3>b??)(?<g4>b?)$` . You're allowing the regex to capture a part of your string.

Comment: Thanks Kobi, that's what I would have suiggested to Stuff also.